# Parallel array vs array of struct

Tags: arrays, c

When would a parallel array be more efficient (CPU, memory, etc) than an array of `struct`? What are the pros and cons of using a parallel array over an array of `struct`?

For the record, a parallel array refers to multiple arrays (of same size) where each element at index N is somehow related to the elements at the same index of all other arrays:

```
char *names[] = {"Alice", "Bob", "Carl"};
int ages[] = {45, 34, 72};
```

Whereas an array of struct would do this:

```
struct {
    char *name;
    int age;
} people = {{"Alice", 45}, {"Bob", 34}, {"Carl", 72}};
```

Comment: parallel arrays can be very useful for stuff that lends itself to SIMD operations.

Comment: Correction: `} people = {` should be `} people[] = {`... A common objective is to fill _records_ with attributes of objects (eg: `name` and `age`), then sort and/or filter the collection for some purpose. You don't want to be attempting that with "parallel arrays"... Code that is difficult to read/understand (and may contain bugs) is **extremely** inefficient... Go with what works best...

Comment: From a _performance_ stand point, I think `char ages[] = {45, 34, 72};` should be considered as the [oldest person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanne_Calment) is less than `CHAR_MAX`.

Comment: You could also place the two arrays in a single `struct`.

Comment: OT: `age` should not be used. A person's age (or a dog's age) changes with every second that passes. The _information_ is stale when used (although relative ages may be considered stable.) Better to use `dob` (Date of Birth) that is unchanging...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica We shouldn't use `char` for the purpose of storing numbers. Use `uint8_t` and then as a bonus we also solve the situation when someone makes it past 127 years.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, other narrows types have their advantages.

Answer (score 3):

#### Cache efficiency

If you are going to access the age of multiple people sequentially and not their name, then having all the ages closer in memory (as would be the case with a parallel array) would improve data locality and thus cache efficiency.

On the contrary, if you are going to access the age **and** name of someone and then the age **and** name of someone else, etc. the the superior choice would be an array of struct, for the same reason. The closer in time accesses would require less jumps in memory.

So which one you choose really depends on how you will be accessing the data.

#### Padding

The structures may contain padding to align them to a power of 2 to make indexing them fast. This may waste space unless the structures are already a power of 2 size to begin with.

Parallel arrays will not have any wasted padding space.

#### Readability and maintainability

Finding the corresponding element of an certain element in a different parallel array can be a nightmare. But with an array of struct, this is easy. Array of structs are more maintainable.

Comment: Structures may certainly be padded to some multiple for alignment, but I'm not aware of any compiler that forces the size to a power of 2.

Comment: You didn't mention debugging.  Parallel arrays may make seeing the related values difficult or awkward, while seeing the related values in a struct is almost automatic.  Or was that the point of your last paragraph?

Comment: "_If you are going to access the age [but] not their name,_" then there is no purpose in having the names in RAM... Not a valid argument...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Let's consider a task of looking for the oldest (or the youngest) person in a dataset. You'll need to iterate all elements of `ages` but only single access with known index to `names`.

Comment: @dimich "_If you are going to access the age [but]_ **not their name**," Don't look at me! I didn't write this answer...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I think in *to access the age of multiple people sequentially* words *multiple* and *sequentially* are significant. Sorry for stuffy comment but i believe it's obvious what they meant.

Comment: @Fe2O3 in addition to [three alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77554519/parallel-array-vs-array-of-struct?noredirect=1#comment136724490_77554520), then there is also round: away, toward zero, nearest ties even, nearest ties away, nearest ties ..., [stochastic](https://nhigham.com/2020/07/07/what-is-stochastic-rounding/), [random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_rounding) and even more.   I guess there are 2 types of people in the world, those who divide thing in 2 and those who do not. 

Comment: It’s easier to sort an array of structures (use `qsort()`) than to sort parallel arrays (no standard function).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "2 types of people"... if one _rounds_ the number of categories...  `:-)`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In some cases it makes sense to sort separate array of indices (keys). And here we go into rabbit hole of database normalization :)

Answer (score 1):

> When would a parallel array be more efficient (CPU, memory, etc) than an array of struct?

Either one has performance advantages depending on how code uses the data.

Yet parallel arrays are hard to 1) maintain (see below as an example) and 2) hard to organize and so optimize the higher level code (where orders of magnitude performance optimizations are possible).

IMO this *linear* performance concern does not fall into the 3% of [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/94903) exception and should be avoided.

---

**Coherency**

Consider trying to determine the number of elements and keeping them consistent across separate *members*:  `names[]`, `ages[]` with OP's idea - and variations on it.

```
char *names1[] = {"Alice", "Bob", "Carl"};
int ages1[] = {45, 34, 72};
foo bar1[] = { ... };
```

versus

```
char *names2[] = {"Alice", "Bob", "Carl"};
int ages2[sizeof names2/sizeof names2[0]] = {45, 34, 72};
foo bar2[sizeof names2/sizeof names2[0]] = { tbd };
```

versus

```
char *names3[] = {"Alice", "Bob", "Carl", "Dan"};
int ages3[sizeof names3/sizeof names3[0]] = {45, 34, 72};
foo bar3[sizeof names3/sizeof names3[0]] = { tbd };
```

versus

```
#define N 3
char *names4[N] = {"Alice", "Bob", "Carl", "Dan"};
int ages4[N] = {45, 34, 72};
foo bar4[N] = { tbd };
```

versus

```
char *names5[] = {"Alice", "Bob", "Carl", "Dan"};
int ages5[] = {45, 34, 72};
static_assert(sizeof names5 / sizeof names5[0] == sizeof ages5 / sizeof age5[0], "Must be the same");
foo bar5[] = { tbd };
static_assert(sizeof names5 / sizeof names5[0] == sizeof bar5 / sizeof bar5[0], "Must be the same");
```

`ages1[]` has the same number of array elements as `names1[]` only if the array initialization is the same length.
`ages2[]` has the same number of array elements as `names2[]`. It will error if `ages2[]` has too many initializers.  If initialization list is shorter (`arge3[]`), we get 0 for the remaining ages.

How do we determine the number of elements?  At least with `#define N 3`, it is clear yet a short initializer list may go unnoticed.
The `names5[]` approach works better to keep all the *members* in sync.

With a `struct` this is all quite simple.

```
struct {
    char *name;
    int age;
    foo bar;
} people[] = {{"Alice", 45, tbd}, {"Bob", 34, tbd}, {"Carl", 72, tbd}};
```